# Let X be any set and let (Y, T*) be a topological space. Describe the smallest topology for X which makes f continuous.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Can I take coarser topology here to describe this? I need this solution.

Comment: What is $f$ exactly?

Comment: f:X→Y is a map.

Comment: You should get a bit more specific, when asking questions here. It seems like you want to know it for a function $f: X\mapsto Y$? Still, in the future please use your Headline as a headline and describe your question properly, it makes things easier.

Comment: Ok sir. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Yes, I want to know for a function f:X→Y.

Comment: Well, yes, by virtue of "coarse topology" = "small topology", it is true that the smallest topology on $X$ such that $f:X\to (Y,\tau^*)$ is continuous is the coarsest topology such that $f:X\to (Y,\tau^*)$ is continuous.

Comment: Let T be the cofinite topology on R. let I:(R, T)→(R, U) and I*:(R, U)→(R, T) be the identity mappings. Then
 show that (i) I is not continuous. (ii) I* is continuous.

Comment: U is an usual topology on R.

Comment: Can you tell me that one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the topological sense a function $f:X\mapsto Y$ is continuous if the preimage of every open set (i.e. every set $A\in T^*$) is open, which implies that the coarsest topology to make f a continuous function is $f^{-1}(T^*)$.

Comment: Thanks sir.  I appreciate it.

Comment: You can mark post as answering your question. Otherwise others won't be sure if you already have got your answer or if they should put in some extra effort.